# What is the exact difference between --attach STDIN and --interactive?

Tags: docker

The [`docker run` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) claims:

> If you do not specify -a then Docker will attach to both stdout and stderr . You can specify to which of the three standard streams (STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR) you’d like to connect instead, as in:
>
> `$ docker run -a stdin -a stdout -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash`
>
> For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use -i -t together in order to allocate a tty for the container process. -i -t is often written -it as you’ll see in later examples. Specifying -t is forbidden when the client is receiving its standard input from a pipe, as in:
>
> `$ echo test | docker run -i busybox cat`

So, what is the exact difference between

```sh
$ docker run -a stdin -a stdout -a stderr mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver
```

and

```sh
$ docker run -i mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source you find that [`--interactive` is mostly equivalent to `--attach stdin`](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/4a6fe51157bf0199a933f44d1da09685f48fd8dd/cli/command/container/opts.go#L315-L329):

```golang
    var (
        attachStdin  = copts.attach.Get("stdin")
        attachStdout = copts.attach.Get("stdout")
        attachStderr = copts.attach.Get("stderr")
    )

    //...

    if copts.stdin {
        attachStdin = true
    }
```

(Where [`copts.attach` maps to the `--attach` flag](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/4a6fe51157bf0199a933f44d1da09685f48fd8dd/cli/command/container/opts.go#L170) and [`copts.stdin` to `--interactive`](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/4a6fe51157bf0199a933f44d1da09685f48fd8dd/cli/command/container/opts.go#L181))

And since `stdout` and `stderr` are attached by default your two command are equivalent

...mostly: using the `--interactive` flag `stdin` will also be [actually attached](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/4a6fe51157bf0199a933f44d1da09685f48fd8dd/cli/command/container/opts.go#L590-L591) to the `stdin` of the `docker run` client command and [disconnected when the client closes `stdin`](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/4a6fe51157bf0199a933f44d1da09685f48fd8dd/cli/command/container/opts.go#L665-L668):

```golang
    config := &container.Config{
        //...
        OpenStdin:       copts.stdin,
        AttachStdin:     attachStdin,
        //...
    }

    //...

    // When allocating stdin in attached mode, close stdin at client disconnect
    if config.OpenStdin && config.AttachStdin {
        config.StdinOnce = true
    }
```

(I'm actually not quite sure what would be the use case for `-a stdin` since you can not actually attach to it to provide input...)